# How to pass javascript variables values from twig to controller using href path in Symfony2?

Tags: javascript, symfony, variables, twig, href

I would like to know how to pass javascript variables values from twig to controller using href path in Symfony2. this is my code:

```
 <html>
<head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var a = "hello";
        var b = "hi";
        var c = $('<a href="{{ path('ikproj_groupe_homepagegroupe1', {'id': a, 'num': b}) }}">send data</a>');
        $('body').append(c);
    </script>    
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that it displays this message: Variable "a" does not exist .
So, my question is: what is the correct code to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a `twig` variable. Ex:

```
<script>
    {% set a = 'hello' %}
    {% set b = 'hi' %}
    var c = $('<a href="{{ path('ikproj_groupe_homepagegroupe1', {'id': a, 'num': b}) }}">send data</a>');
    $('body').append(c);
</script>
```

Comment: well, just one thing more, let's assume that we have this javascript variable: var groupid1 = parseInt(data1.groupid); ... how can I set it with twig? in fact, if I put {% set groupid1 = parseInt(data1.groupid) %} it displays this error message: The function "parseInt" does not exist .  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can`t mix `JavaScript` and `twig`. First is run on client side and second is executed on serverside (`twig` is already rendered when JS work).

Answer (score 1):

I find the easiest approach to this is to set the path in the original template using an href (or possible a data) attribute like..

```
<a href="{{ path('route_name', {'id': a }) }}" 
            class="some-specific-class">Click</a>
```

Or using a data attribute..

```
<a href="#" data-href="{{ path('route_name', {'id': a }) }}" 
            class="some-specific-class">Click</a>
```

And then in the javascript use..

```
$('a.some-specific-class').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    .. or
    var href = $(this).data('href');

    .. do things with href
});
```

Alternatively you could you the [FOSJSRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle) and pass the id in a data attribute and generate the route from that using..

```
$('a.something').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var id = $(this).data('id'),
        url = Routing.generate('rout_name', {'id': id });

    .. do stuff with url
});
```