# symfony2 how to access twig path by javascript

Tags: javascript, php, symfony

In symfony2, this works fine in the html.twig file:

```
<a class="btn brl-next brl-btn" href="{{ path('new_message') }}">Next</a>
```

but currently, i need to access `path('new_message')` by javascript.

I tried:

```
        nextButtons.each(function () {
            $(this).on('click', function () {
                $("a").prop("href", "{{ path('new_message') }}");
            });
        });
```

But it's not working,  does someone can help me on how to access symfony path by javascript?

Comment: You can use [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle) (develop by SF)

Comment: ^ +1 use that bundle, so you don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: You can add the routes to your anchor tags in your twig template like explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24674562/1791606 . Meaning you can have standalone javascript files rather mixing javascript and html in your template files.

Comment: @Debflav I like the ideao of FOSJsRoutingBundle, but it depends on how often you need that. For just a simple ajax task where you want to define your route in routing.yml you also can make a simple div with an attribute, as i described below :)

Answer (score 1):

Just add an HTML Element with an attribute with the path. I use that e.g for getting my ajax route. See example below:

#### dyncontent.html.twig

```
<div id="dyncontent" class="dyn" data-ajaxurl="{{ path("common_ajax") }}"></div>
```

i need that div for loading data into it, and as path information i have the `data-ajax` attribute with my path defined.

now i can select this path with my Javascript

#### dyncontent.js

```
var ajaxpath =  $("#dyncontent").attr("data-ajaxurl");
$.getJSON(ajaxpath , null, function(data) {
  //get JSON out of the right controller with correct path
}
```

I am not sure what you are trying with your buttons, but you can also make

#### button.html.twig

```
<a class="btn brl-next brl-btn" href="#" data-path="{{ path('new_message') }}">Next</a>
```

and get the information with

#### button.js

```
var new_message_path = $(".brl-btn").attr("data-path");
```

now you have your path in the `new_message_path` variable. But think about making your selector unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like that:

**In your layout.html.twig** define global js vars like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var routes = {
        myroutes:{
            route1:"{{ path('my_symfony_route', {}, true) }}", // the true permits to use relative path
            route1:"{{ path('my_symfony_route2', {}, true) }}" 
        },
    };
</script>
```

Then in **yourjsfile.js** call global depending on your needs

```
nextButtons.each(function () {
    $(this).on('click', function () {
        $("a").prop("href", routes.myroutes.route1);
    });
});
```

I hope this will help you!

Comment: it does not work: it will direct go to : /{{ path('new_message', {}, true) }}

Comment: This is strange, it works for me... could you test your variables visibility via your firebug console?

Comment: are you using FOSJsRoutingBundle ?

Comment: No i don't use FOSJsRouting.

Comment: you can try without options i put in the example: `routes = {
        myroutes:{
            route1:"{{ path('my_symfony_route') }},`

Comment: from my part, it cannot compile {{ path('new_message', {}, true) }} in the javascript

Comment: it will get error says:  No route found for "GET /%7B%7B%20path(%27new_message%27)%20%7D%7D"

Comment: This is strange... Could you confirm that your global JS vars are set in your **layout.html.twig** and that they are visible in your JS Files (check it via firebug console `console.log(routes.myroutes.route1);`)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57680/discussion-between-justin-and-ji-bay).

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I use all the path

For example if your route's name is: "new_message", and the path is `/yourproject/web/app_dev.php/message/new`,you can make like that in javascript:

```
var route='/docMessagerie/web/app_dev.php/protocol/updateProtocol/';
```

It's working for me

Answer (score 0):

You can directly add twig path syntax like this.

```
var commercial = '{{path('_commercial')}}';
```

then you can call like this

```
 window.location = commercial ;
```